# bash script. how to add user's choice into txt file

Tags: bash

I want to let user key in the choice 1-3, then save, then together with the other inputs in the .txt file. I've tried using switch but it doesn't seem to work..
Only a beginner in bash prog..

```
    echo  "Select the Employee Type:"
echo "1- Salaried Employee"
echo "2- Hourly Employee"
echo "3- Commission Employee"
echo -en "Enter Selection: "
read choice

 case $choice in
         "1")  
    Type="Salaried Employee"
      break
      ;;
      "2") 
    Type = "Hourly Employee"
      break
      ;;
      "3") 
    Type ="Commission Employee"
      break
      ;;
          *) echo "Error: Please enter a choice between 1 - 7"
             echo -en "Hit [Enter] to return..."
             read
           ;;
  esac

   `if [ `count_lines "^${Name},"` -ne 0 ]                                                
   then
       echo "Error: Entry already exist!!"
   else 
       confirm "Are you sure you want to add the entry?[y/n]" 
       if [ $? -ne 0 ]
       then
           echo "Previous entry not updated!"           
       else 
           echo "Record is updated with new employee!!"
           echo "${Name},${Job},${Department},${Salary},${Type}" >> $PAYROLL
       fi       
   fi`
```

Comment: Are the ` characters really there in the script, or did you just add them to try to make it display correctly on Stackoverflow?

Comment: Please give us a simple but complete script. You defined several variables (**$Name**, **$Job**, ...) and functions (**count_lines**) which aren't defined in your script. And I don't understand the concrete issue...

Comment: the other variable are working , till i added the final one "EMployee Type '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things wrong with this script:

- At the end of a case alternative, there's only `;;` -- no `break` (which jumps out of do/for/while)
- There's an extra backtick before the `if` and after the `fi` causing a syntax error; remove them
- There must be no spaces around `=` is assigments like `Type = "Hourly Employee"` and `Type ="Commission Employee"`

Comment: hi thanks for pointing that out..
i've edited it. 
but seems like i still can't savev the user's selection to the database.txt file

Comment: For a correct diagnosis you need to tell us exactly what your script is, what you enter, and what messages you expect plus what messages and errors the shell actually outputs. Don't type it, cut and paste it.